# SparkMLlib MultiClassMetrics.confusionMatrix() and precision() seems giving contradictory results

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to machine learning and Spark MLlib. I have created RandomForest classifier model using `RandomForest.trainClassifier()` My training data set is mostly categorical in nature and have response/target variables as Actionable/NoActionable.

I have created `predictionAndLables` `RDD` using test data and `model.predict()` Now I am trying the following to validate my model accuracy.

```
MultiClassMetrics metrics = new MultiClassMetrics(predictionAndLables.rdd())
System.out.println(metrics.precision()); //prints 0.94334140435
System.out.println(metrics.confusionMatrix()); //prints like the following

1948.0     0.0
117.0      0.0
```

Now if you see model accuracy printed using `precision()` method seems really good around `94%` but if you see above confusion matrix something seems wrong I have `1948` NonActionable target variables and `117` Actionable target variable in test data set.

So according to confusion matrix it could predict NonActionable correctly and could not predict at all Actionable variables. I am trying to understand the confusion matrix and why precision is `94%`. So results look contradicting.

Comment: Accuracy = (correctly classified instances)/(total instances) = (1948+0)/(1948+0+117+0) = 0.9433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your 117 Actionable rows are glued to about 500 NonActionable ones. Now the classifier can move all 617 to the Actionable column and get 500 NonActionable ones wrong or it can move them to the NonActionable column and get 117 wrong. Unless you tell it that the 117 Actionable wrong are more wrong than the 500 NonActionable it will do that. Figure out how to balance the problem (fake out more Actionable items, subsample NonActionable ones, weight Actionable items more heavily etc) AND work on more features so as to weaken the "glue" (make Actionable and NonActionable look as different as possible to the classifier)